# jquery this and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This might seem like an old question and there are many pages that explain the difference between those two, but i still dont understand it completely, as both seem to work for me just fine. I think I understood why I cant use `this`  or `$(this)` in my nested function. But why are both alternatives with the variable working? And which would be the proper one that I should use?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.helloWorld = function() {
  var $wrap1    = this;
  var $wrap2    = $(this);

  var keys = function(){
     $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 39) {
           console.log("key pressed");
           event.preventDefault();
           this.fadeOut();            //Does not work
           $(this).fadeOut();         //Does not work      
           $wrap1.fadeOut();          //Does work
           $wrap2.fadeOut();          //Does work
        }
     });
  };
  keys();
}
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: How are you calling `helloWorld`?

Comment: Not sure why you need the `keys` variable - just call the keyup directly.  Also one generally returns `this` from a jQuery extension to allow for chaining (unless you need to return another value).  Yours doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a jQuery `fn` extension, `this` refers to the jQuery object already, therefore `$(this)` is essentially a no-op.

However in most cases, such as event handlers, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event, and you need to use `$(this)` to call jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the function callback (to `keyup`) `this`should be the DOM element triggering the event while `$(this)` is a jQuery object wrapping that element (or a jQuery collection containing only that element).

However, when you are creating the helloWorld extension `this` is the current jQuery object (i.e. whichever jQuery objecty/collection you ran `$().helloWorld()` on.  So in that case `this`and `$(this)` are both jQuery ojects and essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**$(this)** - represent jQuery Object of current DOM element on which event this function is called

**this** - In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

Comment: Not always. See the other answers.